# Find Google place 'reference key' directly via Google (maps) 'cid'

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places-api, google-places

Is it possible to retrieve the Google places 'reference key' **directly** via the Google (maps) 'cid' identifier?

If yes, how?

If no, what are my options? Is there an indirect way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Google api provides mainly 4 searches--

1. nearby (based on latlng and radius)
2. text based (based on some text...eg name of a place,city etc)
3. radarsearch (gives only the reference id)
4. placedetails (this takes the above reference id and provide all details corresponding to that one reference id)

you can find examples and other details [here](http://developers.google.com/places/documentation)...

Comment: Thank you. Could you please be a bit more precise on your answer? For example what is textbase search or nearbyplace search? An example would be very helpful!

Comment: Yes thanks it is clear now. So the answer to my original question is actually "No". Is that correct? If yes maybe then you should add that "No" in your answer.

Comment: is that ok now... and I have told you the indirect way

Comment: perfect! I think now everyone will get it :) thank you @Monash